# Find $k(\neq 0)$ for which the line $x=k$ intersects the curve $xy^2=(x+y)^2$ orthogonally.

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

Find $k(\neq 0)$ for which the line $x=k$ intersects the curve $xy^2=(x+y)^2$ orthogonally.

The first one is a line. Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Does the phrase "implicit differentiation" mean anything to you?

Comment: @Arthur I know "implicit differentiation". Please help me by writing some lines as solution to the problem.

Comment: Just the fact that I _used_ the phrase "implicit differentiation" should hint towards what you should do next (hint: implicitly differentiate the curve).

Comment: @Arthur The slope of the 1st curve is $90^o$ and the slope of tangent to the 2nd curve is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x+2y-y^2}{2xy-2x-2y}$. Also $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ then $2x+2y-y^2=0$  What next?

Comment: Now find all the values of $x$ and $y$ where the point $(x,y)$ is on the curve $xy^2=(x+y)^2$ and the tangent line has zero slope: $2x+2y-y^2=0$. That means solving those simultaneous equations. For each solution (there may be more than one), the value of $k$ will be obvious.

Comment: I should also note that you must beware of extraneous solutions: those that satisfy your two derived equations but do not satisfy your original problem. You will get at least one of those.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I failed to understand your 2nd comment. Please explore.

Comment: Those two equations will have two solutions. Only one of them actually works, because the other one, when finding the slope, results in the expression $\frac 00$. That is an extraneous solution, so your original problem has only one answer. Is that clear? Have you solved the two equations for $x$ and $y$ yet? Have you graphed the original equation to eyeball the solution(s)?

Comment: The solution of $2x+2y-y^2=0$ with $x=k$ and $xy^2=(x+y)^2$ ie sol of $2k+2y-y^2=0$ and $ky^2=(k+y)^2$ is $x=k$ and $y={\frac { \left( 1+\sqrt {k} \right) k}{k-1}}$ and $y=-{\frac { \left( -1+\sqrt {k} \right) k}{k-1}}$.